# Spring Data JPA метод deleteById не удаляет сущность

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-jpa, delete

Метод `deleteById` `Spring Data Jpa` не удаляет объект из БД, хотя отрабатывает.
Читал, что это из-за того, что объект имеет связь `ManyToOne` и ссылка на него остается в родительской сущности, которая хранит список этих объектов, и сначала надо удалить объект из этого списка. Но как это сделать, чтобы не подгружать весь список объектов, которых могут быть тысячи?

Рылся в `PgAdmin` (графический интерфейс управления БД `PostgreSQL`): там я вообще не нашел таблиц связей (вроде `entity1_entity2`) между основными таблицами.

`CascadeType` у меня почему-то тоже не работает.

Именно не получается удалить объект `Comment`, который связан отношением `ManyToOne` к сущностям `Person` и `Task`.

Вот две родительские сущности `Person` и `Task`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @Email
    private String email;
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Пароль должен содержать минимум 5 символов")
    private String password;
    private transient String passwordConfirm;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Task> createdTasks;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "executor")
    private List<Task> executableTasks;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime registrationDate;

    
    public Person(){}

// getters, setters
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Заголовок не может быть пустым")
    private String title;
    @NotBlank(message = "Описание не может быть пустым")
    private String description;
    @NotNull(message = "У задачи должен быть статус")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
    @NotNull(message = "У задачи должен быть приоритет")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Priority priority;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person author;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "executor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person executor;
    @NotNull(message = "У задачи должен быть исполнитель")
    private transient long executorId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
    private List<Comment> comments;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime editedAt;
    
    public Task(){}

// getters, setters
```

Дочерняя сущность `Comment`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Комментарий не может быть пустым")
    private String body;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Task task;
    private transient long taskId;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person author;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime editedAt;
    
    public Comment(){}
    
// getters, setters
```

Метод контроллера:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/comment/delete/confirm/{id}")
    public String deleteComment(@PathVariable long id, Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal PersonDetails pd) {
        Comment comment = commentService.findById(id);
        if (pd == null || comment.getAuthor().getId() != pd.getPerson().getId()) 
            throw new MismatchIdentifierException("ID автора комментария и Ваш не совпадают. Похоже, что Вы не являетесь автором.");
        commentService.deleteById(id);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\ndeleting succesful");
        model.addAttribute("task", comment.getTask());
        return showTask(comment.getTask().getId(), model, pd);
    }
```

В результате выводится сообщение `"deleting succesful"`.

Метод сервиса:

```
    public void deleteById(long id) {
        commentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

Репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * from comments WHERE task_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Comment> findByTask(long id);
    @Query(value = "SELECT * from comments WHERE author_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Comment> findByAuthor(long id);
    Page<Comment> findByAuthor_id(long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Ошибка из-за связей могла бы быть в другом случае: если бы вы, например, попытались удалить `Person`. Ведь на его айдишник имеется ссылка (foreign key) из таблицы `Comment`, и тогда Spring даже выдал бы исключение с соответствующим сообщением. А в вашем случае `Comment` по идее должен свободно удаляться. Так как на него никто foreign key не имеет. Уберите каскад у коммента, он в данном случае лишний: вы таким образом указываете, что хотите вместе с комментом удалить связанную задачу и человека, а, соответственно, и все другие связанные с ними комменты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решением было во-первых повесить аннотацию `@Transactional` над методом в сервисе (так как я выложил не весь код и не упомянул, что у меня над классом сервиса висит аннотация `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`):

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void deleteById(long id) {
        commentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

А во-вторых явно объявить метод удаления с нативным SQL запросом в репозитории:

```
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * from comments WHERE task_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Comment> findByTask(long id);
    @Query(value = "SELECT * from comments WHERE author_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Comment> findByAuthor(long id);
    Page<Comment> findByAuthor_id(long id, Pageable pageable);
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteById(long id);
}
```

Теперь удаление работает.

Каскадирование не отключал - я думаю, там все правильно, тем более что при проверочном удалении объекта `Comment` объекты `Task` и `Person` не удалились.